# Input dataset values into an HTML file?

Tags: html

I have a very basic HTML file (a promotional email) that I'm trying to manipulate to pull in values from a dataset I've got saved locally. Basically I'm looking to input the # of clicks on each link from the email deployment into the HTML to create a visual representation of how many times each link was clicked. A "click map" if you will.

The a tags in the HTML file have unique names, which corresponds to how the data is saved. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" name="google_com">
<a href="http://www.apple.com" name="apple_com">
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" name="stackoverflow_com">
```

Here's what the corresponding [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpCr8.png) looks like.

Any thoughts on how I can tie back the data to the link names in the HTML to visually display the number clicks? My programming skillset is limited to HTML, so if I need to look into a more advanced tactic, I'm just curious where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could try reading the file with JavaScript and building the HTML manually.  (Normally JavaScript isn't ideal for local file system access, but if you're just running this yourself and can *grant* it access, that should work.)  Or you could use just about any programming language to read the file and output a new HTML file that you could then open.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me somewhere to start.